# Taking characters out of list and turning them into other characters

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

I have made a Secret language that I would to be able to put full words into the input and get the output as the list says the letters should be. Let's say for example I input "AB" I would like the output to be "QW".

```
while True:
    print("type sentence you want translated")
    Befor=input()
    After=list(Befor)

    if Befor=="A":
        print("Q")
    elif Befor=="B":
        print("W")
    elif Befor=="C":
        print("E")
    elif Befor=="D":
        print("R")
    else:
        print("--")

    print(After)

pass
```

Comment: Can you please explain what problems you are facing in your implementation? What is happening that is not behaving as you expect?

Comment: I can only do this with one letter at a time and i would like for it to do full words

Comment: It looks like you've just started learning Python. Try experimenting with `for letter in Befor:`, inside of which you could put your `if-elif-else` block.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're inputting two letters, but your test conditions only contain one character each. You should iterate on the input string using a `for` and test each character in the string one at a time:

```
before = input()

for i in before:
    if i=="A":
        print("Q")
    elif i=="B":
        print("W")
    elif i=="C":
        print("E")
    elif i=="D":
        print("R")
    else:
        print("--")
```

You can also improve your code by using a *mapping* instead of the `if/elif` as this will help you accommodate new translations more easily:

```
before = input()
mapping = {'A': 'Q', 'B': 'W', 'C': 'E', 'D': 'R'}

after = ''.join(mapping.get(x, '--') for x in before)
print(after)
```

Notice how the dictionary's `get` method was used to return the default `'--'` when the mapping does not contain the character.

Answer (score 1):

You can auto populate as well,

```
before = input()

mapping = {chr(x):(chr(x+6) if x + 6 < 91 else chr(x+6-26)) for x in range(65,91)} 

print(mapping)

after = ''.join(mapping.get(x, '--') for x in before)
print(after)
```

```
SUBHAM
{'A': 'G', 'B': 'H', 'C': 'I', 'D': 'J', 'E': 'K', 'F': 'L', 'G': 'M', 'H': 'N', 'I': 'O', 'J': 'P', 'K': 'Q', 'L': 'R', 'M': 'S', 'N': 'T', 'O': 'U', 'P': 'V', 'Q': 'W', 'R': 'X', 'S': 'Y', 'T': 'Z', 'U': 'A', 'V': 'B', 'W': 'C', 'X': 'D', 'Y': 'E', 'Z': 'F'}
YAHNGS

[Program finished]
```

Probably wrap around? This is something like a ceaser cipher? Could just reuse alot of stuff already in python

```
def genCipher(offset):
  from collections import deque
  from string import ascii_uppercase
  c = deque(ascii_uppercase)
  c.rotate(-offset)
  return dict(zip(ascii_uppercase, c))

print(genCipher(6))
```

```
 {A': 'G', 'B': 'H', 'C': 'I', 'D': 'J', 'E': 'K', 'F': 'L', 'G': 'M', 'H': 'N', 'I': 'O', 'J': 'P', 'K': 'Q', 'L': 'R', 'M': 'S', 'N': 'T', 'O': 'U', 'P': 'V', 'Q': 'W', 'R': 'X', 'S': 'Y', 'T': 'Z', 'U': 'A', 'V': 'B', 'W': 'C', 'X': 'D', 'Y': 'E', 'Z': 'F'}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are reinventing the wheel, use [`str.translate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate). To use `str.translate`, you need to first create a dictionary that can be used to map the original character to the new character. This transition table can be made using [`maketrans`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.maketrans).

```
>>> mapping = {'A': 'Q', 'B': 'W', 'C': 'E', 'D': 'R'}
>>> str.maketrans(mapping)
{65: 'Q', 66: 'W', 67: 'E', 68: 'R'}
```

Now that we have the table ready, we just need to pass it to `translate`.

```
>>> table = str.maketrans(mapping)
>>> "AB".translate(table)
'QW'
```

Now we get the desired result.

Comment: Not an optimal solution